# Deleting a specific element inside nested python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have a particular function that outputs nested dictionaries corresponding to a list of files like so:

```
{'.gitignore': {}, 'examples': {'apishowcase': {'apishowcase.py': {}, 'static': {'style.css': {}}, 'templates': {'counter.html': {}}}}}
```

I need to delete a specific instance of these dictionaries, for example, with this input:

```
["examples", "apishowcase", "apishowcase.py"]
```

I want to navigate to `dic["examples"]["apishowcase"]` and delete the apishowcase.py dictionary, however, I've been struggling with understanding how exactly I navigate to this specific dictionary since the input lists can have any size and the nested dictionaries vary according to many variables.

Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function that recursively walks into the nested dictionaries until only one key remains, then it calls `.pop` to remove that entry.

```
def remove_item(data, key):
    if len(key) == 1:
        data.pop(key[0])
    else:
        remove_item(data[key[0]], key[1:])
```

Example usage

```
>>> data
{'.gitignore': {}, 'examples': {'apishowcase': {'apishowcase.py': {}, 'static': {'style.css': {}}, 'templates': {'counter.html': {}}}}}
>>> remove_item(data, ["examples", "apishowcase", "apishowcase.py"])
>>> data
{'.gitignore': {}, 'examples': {'apishowcase': {'static': {'style.css': {}}, 'templates': {'counter.html': {}}}}}
```

Could add some error-handling to that function to handle cases where no such key exists, for example.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it. No idea how I didn't see this before!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

```
data = {'.gitignore': {}, 'examples': {'apishowcase': {'apishowcase.py': {}, 'static': {'style.css': {}}, 'templates': {'counter.html': {}}}}}
path = ["examples", "apishowcase", "apishowcase.py"]

reduce(dict.get, path[:-1], data).pop(path[-1])
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'.gitignore': {}, 'examples': {'apishowcase': {'static': {'style.css': {}}, 'templates': {'counter.html': {}}}}}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it!